# Error running bpm generated Ember application

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to follow the directions on this [ud3323/bpm wiki page](https://github.com/ud3323/bpm/wiki/Using-BPM-with-Ember) to create an Ember.js application using bpm. However at the last step (Try It Out!), instead of showing "Congratulations! You are now running Hello World v0.0.1", it is still showing "Hello World". Also I am seeing the following error in Firebug:

Module core/main not found
http://localhost:4020/assets/bpm_libs.js (Line 255)

I have tried the procedure line-by-line on two different computers and I am getting the same error. I have uploaded my zipped project [here](http://archfirst.org/sites/default/files/sources/hello_world.zip). Can someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

One more question: Can the generated app run only using "bpm preview"? I moved the project under apache and when I try to run it I get a "spade undefined" error.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that BPM is no longer under active development.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and I got it working by importing the core module in the `main.js` via `require('./core');` and not with `spade.require('./core')`.

Have you done a `bpm rebuild` before moving to apache?

***UPDATE:***

I've taken a look at your code and the problem is the usage of `spade.require`. You can either just use `require` inside your application files, for example `require('./hello_world)` or `require('hello_world/core')`. Or you can use `spade.require` but then you always have to explicit write your applications name, like `spade.require('hello_world/core')`. You can also mix both but I prefer just using the `require` method.

The second problem was that you haven't included the `templates.js` via `require('./templates')` in your `core.js` file.

So the modified code looks as follows:

**core.js**

```
require('ember'); // load Ember.js dependencies
HelloWorld = Ember.Application.create({
  VERSION:  require('./~package').version
});
```

**main.js**

```
require('./core'); // make sure the app namespace loads first
require('./templates');
Ember.View.create({
   templateName: 'main_page'
}).append();
```

**templates.js**

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['main_page'] = require('./templates/main_page');
```

**templates/main_page.handlebars**

```
Congratulations! You are running HelloWorld v{{HelloWorld.VERSION}}
```

Comment: Tried replacing spade.require('./core') with require('./core') - no difference. Even tried bpm rebuild, then bpm preview - no difference. I am ready to give up on bpm. If I can't get hello world to run, I am not sure I am willing to take this on right now. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Naresh, can you provide a link to a repo which hosts your application? I could take a look at it...

Comment: The source is here: http://archfirst.org/sites/default/files/sources/hello_world.zip. I have not hosted the app anywhere.

Comment: I've updated my answer after looking at your code example. Did this solve your problem?